# How to split Map into two maps based on a condition

Tags: immutable.js

I'm relatively new to React using Immutable.js.
Let's say I have a (Ordered) Map of 30 items, in which some have the color green and some the color red.
Now I want to split this Map into two Maps, one containing the first five green items and the other containing the rest (rest of the green items and red items).

If I had an array, I would just define two result-arrays, iterate through my src-array and put the items in their according result-array. If I did that with immutable.js, I would need to create a new Map every time something changes. Is that still the way to go, or are there faster / more elegant ways to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question right, most elegant way is to use [Map.filter](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/filter)

```js
const { Map } = Immutable;
const sourceMap = new Map({ 
  key1: { color: "red" },
  key2: { color: "green" },
});
const filterMap = c => sourceMap.filter(({ color }) => color === c);
const greenMap = filterMap("green");
const redMap = filterMap("red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Iterating twice feels bad :(